# Unable to make icon inside button bigger

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to place an icon inside a button to select some files. Everything works fine except that that the size of the icon is way too small. The button in which the icon is placed has the right dimensions. This is what it looks like:

[image: btn]

[image: btn2]

[image: btn3]

How do I make my icon bigger?

Relevant html

```html
          <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col size="2">
                <ion-button
                  fill="clear"
                  (click)="popFileChooser()"
                  expand="full"
                  class="btnUpload"
                >
                  <input
                    (change)="onImageSelected($event)"
                    type="file"
                    accept="image/*"
                    multiple
                    #uploader
                    hidden
                  />
                  <ion-icon
                    class="btnIcon"
                    slot="icon-only"
                    color="secondary"
                    name="add-circle"
                  ></ion-icon>
                </ion-button>
              </ion-col>

              <ion-col size="10">
                <ion-row>
                  <ion-col size="auto">
                    <div class="imgWrap" *ngFor="let imgUrl of selectedImages">
                      <img class="imageThumbnail" [src]="imgUrl" />
                      <ion-icon
                        class="icon"
                        color="danger"
                        name="close-circle"
                      ></ion-icon>
                    </div>
                  </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
```

And css

```css
.imgWrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.imgWrap > img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.btnIcon {
  font-size: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that your CSS is overwritten by ionic default CSS.
So, use `!important` to add priority to your CSS , example:

```
.btnIcon {
  font-size: 100px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ion-icon has a size property; set it to large;

```
<ion-icon size="large"></ion-icon>
```

you can also do something like below (In yours *.scss file);

ion-icon { zoom: 2 }

Comment: I've tried both but it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: It could be your input tag which is inside your ion-button. remove it to check if it is the main culprit.

Comment: If the issue is caused by input tag. Try to add label element along it:

<input type="file" accept="image/*" .../>
<label for="fileInput" icon-only ion-button>
    <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
</label>

Answer (score 0):

In your scss you can use:

```css
ion-button {
  ion-icon {
    font-size: 50px;  //your px dimensions!
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work. I can't seem to figure out why not

Comment: It works for me on every ionic project! Maybe something is overwriting your css... You can try with !important or on global.scss for to make a try